# How to download source of website by cmd?

Tags: web, curl, cmd, download, wget

Is there any way to download source of website by using cmd?

I already tried curl and wget but thats allow me only to download main page.
What i want is get source of google site after searching something.

I mean url like that "https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=YBg&q=hello&btnK=Szukaj+w+Google&oq=hello&gs_l=p"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the rendered DOM (not the source).  Tools like curl and wget can get the source of a page (similar to what you'll see when you "View page source" in Chrome).

To get the rendered DOM, you'll need a headless browser that will execute JavaScript.

Here's a list of popular options: https://www.keycdn.com/blog/headless-browsers